# Установка npm пакета глобально, вручную, как это реализовать?

Tags: javascript, cmd, npm

появилась нужда установить [данный пакет](https://github.com/AlexanderWillner/kingraph)

```
npm install -g alexanderwillner/kingraph
```

---

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/alexanderwillnerkingraph.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rge010x1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-05T01_4215_762Z-debug.log
```

Подскажите, я правильно понял, что у npm'a не получается найти данный пакет? Или же проблема в чём-то другом? И если моё предположение верно, то как установить данный пакет вручную, глобально?
Заранее спасибо

upd:
Попробовал сделать тоже самое по средствам yarn:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Да, `npm` не может найти необходимый пакет, для ручной сборки вам необходимо воспользоваться утилитой [npm pack](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-pack), собрать с её помощью пакет, если у вас уже есть сборка, то остается только установить:

```bsh
npm install -g your_module.tgz
```

Так же можно воспользоваться утилитой [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link), но она используется для отладки, но может подойти.